# How to use AS IN in R query

Tags: sql, r

I want to implement 'As IN' in R query 
like "select * from A where no as in(select no from B)" 
Note: this is just a sample query to know how to use AS IN in R

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is off, and `AS` is not part of a `WHERE IN` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE no IN (SELECT no FROM B);
```

I assume you are using `sqldf`, or are making database calls from some other package.  A possibly more performant way of writing your query would use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM A a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B b WHERE a.no = b.no);
```

Comment: yeah im using sqldf

Comment: @KaustavMukherjee then you should consider putting the libraries you are using and a small data/code sample in the question before it gets closed. this is noted in the guidance text that comes up when a new question is started and also noted in the the SO R tag FAQ.